# Pthread: Mutex vs RW-lock in a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, pthreads, mutex

I'm studying pthreads from the Peter Pacheco book, where he proposes this solution to protect a linked list using ptreads:

```
pthread rwlock rdlock(&rwlock);
Member(value);    //search
pthread rwlock unlock(&rwlock);
. . .
pthread rwlock wrlock(&rwlock);
Insert(value);
pthread rwlock unlock(&rwlock);
. . .
pthread rwlock wrlock(&rwlock);
Delete(value);
pthread rwlock unlock(&rwlock);
```

I undestand that many threads can read (`search`) simultaneously any node of the linked list, but just one should be able to write (`Insert`/`Delete`) them at the same time. I wonder why we don't use just a mutex in write functions (`Insert`/`Delete`) and forget everything else:

```
...
Member(value);    //search    
...
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
Insert(value);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
...
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
Delete(value);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
...
```

Would be there any problem?

Comment: Why not use the C++11 `std::mutex` and then `lock_guard`, or at the very least, RAII using `pthreads`?  If the `Insert` function throws an exception, the `unlock` will never get called.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie, I will study about them.

Comment: Basically in this day and age of C++, thread handling looking similar to your example is considered bad practice, unless you can absolutely guarantee that `Insert` or whatever you're doing between the `lock` and `unlock` calls will not `throw`.  That's why objects are created, where the destructor of the object automatically calls the `unlock` are utilized, and not "naked" `lock / unlock` calls as you're showing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use a mutex in the write functions alone, since that would allow the read functions to possibly read inconsistent data (eg, data that is halfway through what's supposed to be an atomic change).

Hence you would need a mutex for writes *and* reads.

The general idea behind a read/write lock is that *any* number of threads can hold a read lock but only *one* can hold a write lock. In addition, you cannot get a write lock until all read locks are released, and you can't get a read lock while a write lock is active.

This allows unfettered parallel access in the situation where everyone just wants to read, an improvement over the mutex method.

Comment: I hadn't thought that, you are right: nothing prevents to execute the read function while other is writing the same object. Thanks a lot @paxdiablo!